# Can a single Gherkin scenario have multiple user roles?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bdd, gherkin

I have the following:

```
As an approver #... ?

Scenario : approve a profile
When : I approve a profile
Then : the profile owner should be notified about his profile's approval 
# (on his android device)
And : I should see the profile as a valid profile
And : guests should be able to see the profile
```

Or I can say :

```
As an owner

Scenario : approve a profile
When : my profile is approved
Then : I should be notified about my profile's approval
...?
```

Since `my profile is approved` is an event , it has multiple consequences in this, and other Bounded Contexts.

Some consequences are immediate and some can become eventually consistent.
And putting a single event in multiple features can lead to difficulty in managing teams, estimating time, etc.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the best move is to you to split in more scenarios.

Comment: What tool uses this format? The colons in every step are unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth:Android studio feature files; that doesn't affect the question.

Comment: No, I was just curious. The colons (except after Scenario) aren't necessary, then; I don't see them in other Android Studio features on the web.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth: Hi Dave, I answered the question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group logical flows 1st by dependency boundaries , and then by user role.

Try to resolve which can be done by a single developer and which can be broken into smaller parts (So lower lead time it will take).

In a `CQRS` system for example when you are using eventual consistency (which should be defined by requirements) you can easily separate `write` requirement's `gherkin` from `read` requirement's `gherkin`. But if immediate consistency is required by your scenarios you'd better not separate the read side's `gherkin` from write side's `gherkin` and let a single developer(or a pair) work on it.

And the user role to my opinion is less important but if your roles are from different BCs you'd better write different `gherkins` for each. Stories should be independent and `task prioritization` is the `Product Owner's job` but I'd rather prioritize some of them based on **Technical** issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly appropriate to have multiple users with different roles in a single scenario. A Gherkin scenario is a scenario of a use case; it's normal for a use case to have multiple actors.

I'd write your scenario something like this:

```
Scenario: User approves a profile
  Given there is a user "owner"
  And there is a user "approver"
  And there is a user "guest"
  And "owner" has a profile
  When "approver" approves the profile
  Then "owner" should be notified that their profile was approved
  And "approver" should see the profile as a valid profile
  And "guest" should see the profile as a valid profile
```

You would probably need more or different steps to give the different users different permissions, but this should give you the idea.

In this scenario the approver is the most important actor, but what you put in the introductory ("As") section depends on the scope of the feature file (what scenarios it contains besides this one). If it covers all uses of profiles it would just be "As a user"; if it covers all profile administration it would be "As a profile administrator"; if it only covers profile approval it would be "As a profile approver".

Answer (score 0):

Use Scenario Ouline and based on some variables that are saved when you do some actions you can add an if or switch to do the validations.

Comment: Sorry, It's about different consequences of a single event. each consequence can have it's specific LOGIC.